# Google Compute - How to create multiple instances for each zone at once

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create multiple instances in one region with multiple zones. For example, I want to create a total of 5 instances in region `us-west2` which will be distributed uniformly in each region by google itself. Currently, I am using [RegionInstanceGroupManager](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionInstanceGroupManagers) by supplementing an `InstanceTemplate` to create multiple VMs. If I request to create equal or less number of VMs compared to the number of zones in a region then all VMs will get created. For example, if I request 3 instances then one instance per zone will get created successfully which are for `us-west2-a`, `us-west2-b`, `us-west2-c`. However, if I request to create 5 instance then first 3 instances will get created but other 2 instances will fail because google only creates one disk per zone. Let me try to illustrate in a very simple way

**Disks**

1. disk-abc - us-west2-a
2. disk-abc - us-west2-b
3. disk-abc - us-west2-c

**Instance Groups**

1. instanceGroup_1

**Instances**

1. instance_1 - us-west2-a (RUNNING)
2. instance_2 - us-west2-b (RUNNING)
3. instance_3 - us-west2-c (RUNNING)
4. instance_4 (WAITING FOR AN AVAILABLE DISK)
5. instance_5 (WAITING FOR AN AVAILABLE DISK)

Here I as you can see three disks got created with same name (because I am using InstanceTemplate). Since I am using RegionInstanceGroupManager I don't have to create create VMs myself. I just give the number of VMs I want to create. However, the problem is about creating disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem which was about setting `diskName` property while creating `InstanceTemplate`. So, google creates only one disk with same name in each zone. My fault was setting disk name so that google can not create more than one disk in each zone.